# The .ticks property doesn't affect my chart

Tags: d3.js

I have 24 categories in my quantitative axis, and I'd like to display around 6 categories. I tried adding .ticks(6) to my axis, like this

```
var xAxis = d3.svg.axis()
              .scale(x)
              .orient("bottom")
              .ticks(6);
```

but my graph still displays all 24 categories. The scale I'm using is

```
var x = d3.scale.ordinal()
          .rangeRoundBands([0, width], .1, 1);
```

Any idea why this would happen?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `.ticks()` function doesn't do anything for ordinal axes. Depending on what exactly you want to do, you might not need an axis anyway -- simply place the labels you want with the points/bars/whatever you add for the categories.

Comment: Hmm, I think this is a little over my head. Do any of the examples have what you're talking about?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do? I can't help you if I don't know what you're looking for :)

Comment: Sorry :) I have each hour in a day (12am, 1am, 2pm, etc. thru 11pm). They are not dates because they span multiple months, so they're categories. I just don't have enough space to display them all, so I'd like to show about six: 2am, 6am, 10am, 2pm, 6pm, 10pm. Something like that.

Comment: Sounds like the easiest thing to do in this case would be to pretend that they're dates for the sake of the axis. This would allow you to use the convenience functions d3 provides to select the interval at which you want to show labels.

Comment: Got it. Is there a way to suppressing a date from displaying? I.e. I want 3am, 6am, etc. but no Tue 25.

Comment: Yes, see [`tickFormat()`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Scales#wiki-tickFormat).

Comment: Thanks. It still seems like an ordinal scale is most appropriate, even if it'll be harder to figure out. Once I move to implementing updating (right now I just refresh), do you know if I'll be able to update the chart smoothly? I'm worried that the different dates will cause the updating to fail, or at least to not work as expected.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/22775/discussion-between-sam-selikoff-and-lars-kotthoff)